# First and Second input from a form give back 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, backend

So basically I want to create a form that collects user's information and store it in database. Well the problem is that 'fname' and 'name'(the first 2 inputs from the form), for some reason, return 'null' even though they have been filled with text. The problem there is that I cannot add another user due to the fact that there is already a user with the given 'lname' and 'fname' -- in this case 'null'. The strangest part to me is that the other inputs seem to have no problem whatsoever. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

My user.js Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   firstName: {type: String, unique:true},
   lastName: {type: String, unique:true},
   email: {type: String, unique: true},
   hasVoted: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

My form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>POll</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/landing.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>



<div class="row">
    <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment">Comment(Optional)</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes and create mongodb

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var User = require("../models/user");

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("landing");
});

router.post("/", function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to campgrounds array
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var comment = req.body.comment;
    var newUser = {fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, comment: comment};
    // Create a new campground and save to DB
    User.create(newUser, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(newlyCreated);
            //redirect back to campgrounds page
            res.redirect("/", {user: newlyCreated});
        }
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
var newUser = {fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, comment: comment};
```

be this:

```
var newUser = {firstName: fname, lastName: lname, email: email, comment: comment};
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't fix it.. :(

Comment: You could try changing the input names accordingly?